# dependency hell with python-apt

Tags: python, pip, apt, python-venv

I am building a package which is dependent on two packages, which are difficult to handle.

The two problematic packages are:

- python-apt ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/python-apt/), [Docs](https://apt-team.pages.debian.net/python-apt/library/index.html))
- python-pam ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/python-pam/))

#### What is the issue with those packages?

python-apt is installed by apt which I first thought, would be great, since I planned to handle dependencies with apt.

Until I realized that python3-pam is indeed not the python-pam package listed at PyPI.

My first approach was to package python-pam myself, but realized that the project has a few issues with packaging. In the end I plan actually to fix them as well, but decided to push this to a later date.

In the meantime to test my package, I went to simple venv approach.

Until I realized, that python-apt is not just

```bash
pip install python-apt
```

Is it somehow possible to install `python-apt` via pip or bring the system installation inside the venv, until I am able to provide an updated version of `python-pam` deb-package?

Comment: I recommend you edit your question to provide links to the dependencies you mention (either on PyPI, or apt repositories, and possibly source code repositories as well (git, etc.)).

Comment: Sorry, what's the question? This is more like a rant. Check out [ask].

Comment: You are absolutely right. I had the question in my mind but didn't deliver it to text.

Comment: My workaround for the moment is to symlink the dist-packages into my venv, but that does not satisfy.